# How to run a piece of code such that it doesn't steal all the focus to itself in QtQuick?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qml, qthread

I have a C++ class. It inherits a parent class which inherits `QQuickItem`.  Therefore now I  can't inherit from `QThread` since the `QQuickItem` is already there.
*(Error if tried: `Object is an ambiguous base of 'xClass'`)*

*My class has been registered by `qmlRegisterType` and I can access its methods through QML.*

There is a piece of code which runs when a button is pressed from **QML**. This piece of code takes a lot of time to execute and it steals the focus from **QML** window **totally**.

**How to write a piece of code in my C++ class which when I run doesn't steal all the focus to itself?**

Comment: Perhaps you should explain your problem more clearly. Do you have some long blocking operation in your `C++` code which you would like to move to a new thread?

Comment: @thuga  there is a piece of code which runs when a button is pressed from QML. This piece of code takes a lot of time to execute and it steals the focus from QML window totally. I can't click anywhere on QML window till this piece of code completes its excution.

Comment: Well you could move this long blocking operation to a new thread for example by [creating a worker object by subclassing `QObject`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qthread.html#details). Use signals and slots to signal when the operation should start, and to return the data once it has finished. It's hard to say what the best option would be without knowing more about the blocking peace of code.

Comment: @thugs, thanks, but do I have to create a new class for that functionality? Will I have able to derive from QObject when I already have derived from QQuickItem?

Comment: I meant that it should be a separate worker object. Only subclass `QObject`. Different threading technologies are listed [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/threads-technologies.html). You can check them out to see what would work the best for your problem.

Comment: @thuga could you convert your helpful comments to "answers"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to move a blocking process to a new thread is to [create a worker object by subclassing `QObject`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qthread.html#details). Then use signals and slots to signal when the thread should process some data and to return the data.

Here is an example from Qt docs:

```
class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    void doWork(const QString &parameter) {
        QString result;
        /* ... here is the expensive or blocking operation ... */
        emit resultReady(result);
    }

signals:
    void resultReady(const QString &result);
};

class Controller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QThread workerThread;
public:
    Controller() {
        Worker *worker = new Worker;
        worker->moveToThread(&workerThread);
        connect(&workerThread, &QThread::finished, worker, &QObject::deleteLater);
        connect(this, &Controller::operate, worker, &Worker::doWork);
        connect(worker, &Worker::resultReady, this, &Controller::handleResults);
        workerThread.start();
    }
    ~Controller() {
        workerThread.quit();
        workerThread.wait();
    }
public slots:
    void handleResults(const QString &);
signals:
    void operate(const QString &);
};
```

You can find more threading technologies [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/threads-technologies.html). Check them all out and decide which one suits your needs the best.